# Joystick Not behaving properly unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a free joystick pack off the unity asset store that I am modifying. I am using touch fields along with the joys sticks to control the player movement and looking. Everything works just fine in unity itself, however when i build it out to my android phone, the very first time i interact with the joysticks they move around and reposition just fine as i drag around. After this first interaction with them however they no longer reposition as I drag and I am stumped.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FixedTouchField : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, 
IDragHandler
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 TouchDist;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 PointerOld;
    [HideInInspector]
    protected int PointerId;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool Pressed;

    public FixedJoystick joystick;
    public Image joystickHandle;

    private float timeTakenDuringLerp = 1.0f;
    private float timeStartedLerping;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Pressed)
        {
            float timeSinceStarted = Time.time - timeStartedLerping;
            float percentageComplete = timeSinceStarted / timeTakenDuringLerp;
            joystick.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(new Color(1,1,1,0), Color.white, percentageComplete);
            joystickHandle.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(1, 1, 1, 0), Color.white, percentageComplete);
            if (PointerId >= 0 && PointerId < Input.touches.Length)
            {
                TouchDist = Input.touches[PointerId].position - PointerOld;
                PointerOld = Input.touches[PointerId].position;
            }
            else
            {
                TouchDist = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y) - PointerOld;
                PointerOld = Input.mousePosition;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            float timeSinceStarted = Time.time - timeStartedLerping;
            float percentageComplete = timeSinceStarted / timeTakenDuringLerp;
            joystick.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, new Color(1, 1, 1, 0), percentageComplete);
            joystickHandle.color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, new Color(1, 1, 1, 0), percentageComplete);
            TouchDist = new Vector2();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Pressed = true;
        PointerId = eventData.pointerId;
        PointerOld = eventData.position;
        timeStartedLerping = Time.time;
        joystick.RepostionJoystick(eventData);
    }



    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Pressed = false;
        joystick.input = Vector2.zero;
        joystick.handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        joystick.RepostionJoystick(eventData);
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public float Horizontal { get { return (snapX) ? SnapFloat(input.x, AxisOptions.Horizontal) : input.x; } }
    public float Vertical { get { return (snapY) ? SnapFloat(input.y, AxisOptions.Vertical) : input.y; } }
    public Vector2 Direction { get { return new Vector2(Horizontal, Vertical); } }

    public float HandleRange
    {
        get { return handleRange; }
        set { handleRange = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

    public float DeadZone
    {
        get { return deadZone; }
        set { deadZone = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

    public AxisOptions AxisOptions { get { return AxisOptions; } set { axisOptions = value; } }
    public bool SnapX { get { return snapX; } set { snapX = value; } }
    public bool SnapY { get { return snapY; } set { snapY = value; } }

    [SerializeField] private float handleRange = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float deadZone = 0;
    [SerializeField] private AxisOptions axisOptions = AxisOptions.Both;
    [SerializeField] private bool snapX = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool snapY = false;

    [SerializeField] protected RectTransform background = null;
    [SerializeField] public RectTransform handle = null;
    private RectTransform baseRect = null;

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Camera cam;

    public Vector2 input = Vector2.zero;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        HandleRange = handleRange;
        DeadZone = deadZone;
        baseRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        if (canvas == null)
            Debug.LogError("The Joystick is not placed inside a canvas");

        Vector2 center = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        background.pivot = center;
        handle.anchorMin = center;
        handle.anchorMax = center;
        handle.pivot = center;
        handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

   public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
        //    OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void RepostionJoystick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        cam = null;
        if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
            cam = canvas.worldCamera;

        Vector2 position = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(cam, background.position);
        Vector2 radius = background.sizeDelta / 2;
        input = (eventData.position - position) / (radius * canvas.scaleFactor);
        FormatInput();
        HandleInput(input.magnitude, input.normalized, radius, cam);
        handle.anchoredPosition = input * radius * handleRange;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleInput(float magnitude, Vector2 normalised, Vector2 radius, Camera cam)
    {
        if (magnitude > deadZone)
        {
            if (magnitude > 1)
                input = normalised;
        }
        else
            input = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void FormatInput()
    {
        if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
            input = new Vector2(input.x, 0f);
        else if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Vertical)
            input = new Vector2(0f, input.y);
    }

    private float SnapFloat(float value, AxisOptions snapAxis)
    {
        if (value == 0)
            return value;

        if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Both)
        {
            float angle = Vector2.Angle(input, Vector2.up);
            if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
            {
                if (angle < 22.5f || angle > 157.5f)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Vertical)
            {
                if (angle > 67.5f && angle < 112.5f)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
                }
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > 0)
                return 1;
            if (value < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //input = Vector2.zero;
        //handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    protected Vector2 ScreenPointToAnchoredPosition(Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        Vector2 localPoint = Vector2.zero;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(baseRect, screenPosition, cam, out localPoint))
        {
            Vector2 pivotOffset = baseRect.pivot * baseRect.sizeDelta;
            return localPoint - (background.anchorMax * baseRect.sizeDelta) + pivotOffset;
        }
        return Vector2.zero;
    }
}

public enum AxisOptions { Both, Horizontal, Vertical }
```

these are the scripts interacting with each other to reposition the joysticks

Here is the original joystick without the modifications for the touchfield

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public float Horizontal { get { return (snapX) ? SnapFloat(input.x, AxisOptions.Horizontal) : input.x; } }
    public float Vertical { get { return (snapY) ? SnapFloat(input.y, AxisOptions.Vertical) : input.y; } }
    public Vector2 Direction { get { return new Vector2(Horizontal, Vertical); } }

    public float HandleRange
    {
        get { return handleRange; }
        set { handleRange = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

    public float DeadZone
    {
        get { return deadZone; }
        set { deadZone = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

public AxisOptions AxisOptions { get { return AxisOptions; } set { axisOptions = value; } }
public bool SnapX { get { return snapX; } set { snapX = value; } }
public bool SnapY { get { return snapY; } set { snapY = value; } }

[SerializeField] private float handleRange = 1;
[SerializeField] private float deadZone = 0;
[SerializeField] private AxisOptions axisOptions = AxisOptions.Both;
[SerializeField] private bool snapX = false;
[SerializeField] private bool snapY = false;

[SerializeField] protected RectTransform background = null;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform handle = null;
private RectTransform baseRect = null;

private Canvas canvas;
private Camera cam;

private Vector2 input = Vector2.zero;

protected virtual void Start()
{
    HandleRange = handleRange;
    DeadZone = deadZone;
    baseRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
    if (canvas == null)
        Debug.LogError("The Joystick is not placed inside a canvas");

    Vector2 center = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    background.pivot = center;
    handle.anchorMin = center;
    handle.anchorMax = center;
    handle.pivot = center;
    handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    OnDrag(eventData);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    cam = null;
    if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
        cam = canvas.worldCamera;

    Vector2 position = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(cam, background.position);
    Vector2 radius = background.sizeDelta / 2;
    input = (eventData.position - position) / (radius * canvas.scaleFactor);
    FormatInput();
    HandleInput(input.magnitude, input.normalized, radius, cam);
    handle.anchoredPosition = input * radius * handleRange;
}

protected virtual void HandleInput(float magnitude, Vector2 normalised, Vector2 radius, Camera cam)
{
    if (magnitude > deadZone)
    {
        if (magnitude > 1)
            input = normalised;
    }
    else
        input = Vector2.zero;
}

private void FormatInput()
{
    if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
        input = new Vector2(input.x, 0f);
    else if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Vertical)
        input = new Vector2(0f, input.y);
}

private float SnapFloat(float value, AxisOptions snapAxis)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return value;

    if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Both)
    {
        float angle = Vector2.Angle(input, Vector2.up);
        if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
        {
            if (angle < 22.5f || angle > 157.5f)
                return 0;
            else
                return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Vertical)
        {
            if (angle > 67.5f && angle < 112.5f)
                return 0;
            else
                return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (value > 0)
            return 1;
        if (value < 0)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    input = Vector2.zero;
    handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
}

protected Vector2 ScreenPointToAnchoredPosition(Vector2 screenPosition)
{
        Vector2 localPoint = Vector2.zero;
        if 
(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(baseRect, screenPosition, cam, out localPoint))
        {
            Vector2 pivotOffset = baseRect.pivot * baseRect.sizeDelta;
            return localPoint - (background.anchorMax * 
baseRect.sizeDelta) + pivotOffset;
        }
        return Vector2.zero;
    }
}

public enum AxisOptions { Both, Horizontal, Vertical }
```

I gutted all the above from the project and added https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/ultimate-touchpad-108921 to the project without altering anything. It is doing the exact same thing.

Comment: i dont see the class FixedJoystick its a mistake?

Comment: FixedJoystick inherits joystick and is just an empty class

Comment: if you are using the original pack have you the same problem on mobile?

Comment: After taking the time to quickly set it up in another project using the joysticks without the touchfields and my modified code to make them work it does seem to work fine on mobile